# Библиотека на ARM архитектуре

Tags: компилятор, windows-phone-8, arm, x86

У меня есть программа для Windows Phone 8, и она работает на x86 архитектуре, но когда я делаю build на ARM архитектуру, не распознает библиотеку и выходит error (Cannot find assembly, which may contain managed resources that need to be included in this app package).Можно ли как-то портировать эту библиотеку, либо есть какие-то другие решения этой проблемы?